# Solving $12n + 2n + 80 \times 2 \times 4.92 = 200n$ for $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please help me with this?

I'm studying chemistry for the medicine exam, and I haven't done math in a long time

$$12n + 2n + 80 \times 2 \times 4.92 = 200n$$

I need to find $n$.

If someone can please explain me how to do it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: is it $2^n$ or $2n$ ?

Comment: Step one: Multiply the numbers and simplify as far as you can. You should get an expression of the form
$$
\text{something}\cdot n + \text{something} = \text{something}\cdot n
$$
Can you get it to this form?

Comment: Is your equation $12n+2n +80\times 2\times 4.92=200n$?   It's hard to guess from what you wrote.  Why write 1*2n for $2n$, for instance?

Comment: @Duicug Hi !! Welcome To MSE!! Kindly add your thoughts in the process of attempting the question .

Comment: @lulu  thanks, yes. that is my equation

Comment: Ok, so it is of the form $an+bn+c=dn$, for numerical constants $a,b,c,d$.  We can rewrite that as $c=(d-a-b)n\implies n=\frac c{d-a-b}$,trusting that $d-a-b\neq 0$.

Comment: In step one (descibed by Matti P.): add the numbers you can add. Treat $n$ as apples if that helps to think about it: 12 apples + 2 apples = 14 apples.

Comment: I imagine you are capable of siplifying $12n+2n$ yourself. And also $80\times 2\times 4.92$. So what does that get you?

Comment: @Duicug you must try to learn math, pal.... it is inevitable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$12n + 2n + 80 \times 2 \times 4.92 = 200n$

$\Rightarrow 14n + 160 \times 4.92 = 200n$

$\Rightarrow 14n + 787.2 = 200n$

$\Rightarrow 782.2 = 200n - 14n$

$\Rightarrow 782.2 = 186n$

$\Rightarrow 186n = 782.2$

$\Rightarrow n = \dfrac{782.2}{186}$

$\Rightarrow n = 4.23226$

Comment: nice answer..... you tried to get the decimal as well... bravo !

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the left side terms having $n$ to the RHS to get $80 \times 2 \times 4.92 = 186n \implies 4.92 = \dfrac{186n}{160} = \dfrac{93n}{80} \implies 93n = 393.6 = 93n \implies n = \dfrac{393.6}{93} = \dfrac{131.2}{31}$ 
Hope you get it (as well as what you get from the division).

It's a simple problem, actually...